# Specify openvpn/wireguard server outbound interface

Tags: vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I have an openvpn/wireguard server on my VPS, and my VPS has 2 interfaces eth0/eth1, which both can access the Internet. But I want all my vpn outbound traffic to go through eth1. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Linux server, use *policy routing* via `ip rule`:

1. Add a rule to use a different routing table for packets that are sent from your VPN prefix:

   ```
   ip -4 rule add pref 500 from <vpn_network_ipv4> lookup 2
   ip -6 rule add pref 500 from <vpn_network_ipv6> lookup 2
   ```
2. Add a default route through the eth1 gateway to the new routing table:

   ```
   ip -4 route add default via <ipv4_gateway> table 2
   ip -6 route add default via <ipv6_gateway> table 2
   ```

   If you're using DHCP or SLAAC for eth1, tell your DHCP client to put routes in that table instead. (Systemd-networkd has that as an option, I'm not sure about others.)
3. If the VPN clients need LAN access, the local subnet routes must be manually added to the new table as well. Special routes that indicate "check the next rule" can be used:

   ```
   ip -4 route add throw 192.168.0.0/16 table 2
   ip -6 route add throw fd00::/8 table 2
   ```

Comment: I wonder if the OP is facing multihome problem (with or without the forwarding problem).

Comment: Possibly, but the answer is similar for both, just with a different `from` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Set the route for the IP address of the remote VPN endpoint out the gateway associated with the eth1 connection.